# Confusion about the covariant derivative of basis vectors

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

While looking for the derivation of the expression for the covariant derivative, I found a specific derivation used in many videos about general relativity:

Given a vector $\textbf{v} = v^a e_a$ where $e_a$ are the basis vectors of the vector space and $v^a$ are the components of $\textbf{v}$ with respect to the basis.

The change in  $\textbf{v}$  with respect to the basis is given by:
$$ \frac{d\textbf{v}}{dx^v} = \frac{d(v^a e_a)}{dx^v} = \frac{dv^a}{dx^v}e_a + \frac{de_a}{dx^v}v^a $$
Then expressing the change in the basis vector as:  $\frac{de_a}{dx^v} = \Gamma^\mu _{va} e_\mu$ we get:
$$ \frac{d\textbf{v}}{dx^v}  = \frac{dv^a}{dx^v}e_a + \Gamma^\mu _{va} v^ae_\mu = \frac{dv^a}{dx^v}e_a + \Gamma^a _{v \mu} v^\mu e_a $$
Then the covariant derivative is defined as:
$$ \nabla_v v^a e_a= (\frac{dv^a}{dx^v} + \Gamma^a _{v \mu} v^\mu )e_a $$
$$ \nabla_v v^a = \frac{dv^a}{dx^v} + \Gamma^a _{v \mu} v^\mu  $$

In this derivation, the parallel transport of the basis vector is defined to be the same as the regular derivative of the basis vector.

However, when looking at the Wikipedia page for the covariant derivative, it is the covariant derivative of the basis vector that is set equal to its parallel transport:
$$\nabla_v e_a = \Gamma^\mu _{va} e_\mu$$
which implies that the regular derivative of the basis vector is zero:
$$\frac{de_a}{dx^v} = 0 $$

This is very confusing, I think I'm missing something about the notation used in the derivation I showed or mixing between different notations. Any clarification on the subject would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I made a typo with the indices and now it's fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies slightly in the use of what you call "regular derivative". The vector fields in question are not functions taking values on some $\mathbb{R}^N$; instead they are functions taking value on the manifold itself. So the expression $\frac{d v}{dx^{\mu}}$ is not well defined. How can you vary a function with respect to $x^{\mu}$ if the function doesn't depend on it?
This is what the notion of covariant derivative seeks to solve. How to find the notion of directional differentiation in a manifold? The answe is abstraction: forget about what it means, take the example of directional derivative in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and generalize its main properties, like being linear (in the direction and in the vector field slots), respecting the product rule (here we generalize to the tensor product, but it's quite the same idea), making the directional derivative of a scalar function just the image of its derivative along that direction, etc. If we do this we arrive at a notion of directional differentiation which we call directional derivative. So let's apply it to a generic vector field and see what it yields, like you did. We have, along some direction (let's choose a basis vector for simplicity) $e_j$, \begin{equation}\nabla_jv=\nabla_j (v^{\sigma}e_{\sigma})=(\nabla_jv^{\sigma})e_{\sigma}+v^{\sigma}\nabla_j e_{\sigma}\end{equation}
because the covariant derivative respects the product rule; then you do what you did, you write $\nabla_jv^{\sigma}$ as $\partial_j v^{\sigma}$, because it is a property of covariant differentiation that the covariant derivative of a scalar function is just a its directional derivative, and then, you **define** the components of $\nabla_j e_{\sigma}$ to be some functions $\Gamma_{j\,\sigma}^{\mu}$. This you already knew; I'm just illustrating that there is no "regular" derivative anywhere. It's all the covariant derivative. Now I hope your confusion goes away in why the "regular" derivative of the parallel transport of a basis vector is zero; that "regular derivative of the basis" is in fact not that, but it is the partial derivative of the components that goes to zero(and in those it makes sense to talk about partial differentiation, because they're functions on $\mathbb{R}^N$). That's to be expected because the components of the basis vector fields are just the constants $\delta_i^j$.
So, in short, there is no "regular" derivative of vector fields, and the thing that is zero along parallel transport of basis vectors is the partial derivative of the components of the basis vectors.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use an index more than twice.

$\vec{v}=v^\alpha \vec{e_\alpha}$

$\frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial x^\beta}=\frac{\partial v^\alpha}{\partial x^\beta}\vec{e_\alpha}+v^\alpha \frac{\partial \vec{e_\alpha}}{\partial x^\beta}$

Remember the Christofel Symbol $\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha \beta}$ is the $\mu$ component of the $\beta$ derivative of the basis vector $\vec{e_\alpha}$. The derivative is a vector in its own right with the Christoffel symbol indicating components.

$\frac{\partial \vec{e_\alpha}}{\partial x^\beta}=\Gamma_{\alpha \beta}^\mu \vec{e_\mu}$

Swap dummy indices.

$v^\alpha_{;\beta}=\frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial x^\beta}=\frac{\partial v^\alpha}{\partial x^\beta} \vec{e_\alpha}+v^\alpha\Gamma_{\alpha \beta}^\mu \vec{e_\mu}$

$v^\alpha_{;\beta}=\frac{\partial v^\alpha}{\partial x^\beta} \vec{e_\alpha}+v^\mu\Gamma_{\mu \beta}^\alpha \vec{e_\alpha}=(\frac{\partial v^\alpha}{\partial x^\beta} +v^\mu\Gamma_{\mu \beta}^\alpha) \vec{e_\alpha}$

Could be wrong, I thought the criterion for parallel transport was $(\frac{\partial v^\alpha}{\partial x^\beta} =-v^\mu\Gamma_{\mu \beta}^\alpha) $ and so the full covariant derivative is zero.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my typo, now it's fixed